# How to read in a string over tcp socket in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, tcp, client

If I have a java tcp server sending some text, how do I read that text from an `NSInputStream` and store it in a string?

Here is a chunk of code I have, but I'm not really sure how to get a string from here:

```
NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(addr, port: port, inputStream: &inp, outputStream: &out)

let inputStream = inp!
let outputStream = out!
inputStream.open()
outputStream.open()

var readByte :UInt8 = 0
while inputStream.hasBytesAvailable {
    inputStream.read(&readByte, maxLength: 1)
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Have a look at these **awesome** Libraries, they will save your life.

Swift:
[Starscream](https://github.com/hanton/Starscream)

Objective-C:
[Jetfire](https://github.com/acmacalister/jetfire)
[SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket)

Comment: The Starscream library is a Websockets client. It's specifically for communicating with Websockets servers, not for making arbitrary TCP connections.

Answer (score 4):

With your code you can read only 1 byte every time inside your loop. If yo need to read all data, you can do this for example:

```
NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(addr, port: port, inputStream: &inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)
inputStream!.open()
outputStream!.open()

let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_async(queue) {
    let bufferSize = 1024
    var inputBuffer = Array<UInt8>(count:bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)
    while true {
        let bytesRead = self.inputStream!.read(&inputBuffer, maxLength: bufferSize)

        // Here get string from byte Array
        let responseString = NSString(bytes: inputBuffer, length: inputBuffer.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        println("Data from Stream = \(responseString)")
    }
}
```

Here thisl line:

```
let responseString = NSString(bytes: inputBuffer, length: inputBuffer.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
```

create `String` from input byte Array